# Manifest tags declare dynamically

Tags: android, tags

```
//Manifest file
<receiver    
      android:exported="true"
      android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
<action  android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Can we create/add the android:enabled tags dynamically in code?

Comment: Are you saying you want to enable/disable that `<receiver>` from your code?

Comment: I don't think so it's possible from java code

Comment: @Surya did you find solution for this?

Comment: @John . Nope I didn't get a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your gradle code on the module level:

```
// modify AndroidManifest.xml
variant.processManifest.doLast {
    copy {
        from("${buildDir}/manifests") {
            include "${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
        into("${buildDir}/manifests/$variant.name")

        filter {
            String line ->
                line.replaceAll("android:enabled=\"true\"/>",
                        "android:enabled=\"false\"")
        }

        // set the path to the modified Manifest:
        def manifestPath = "${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
        variant.processResources.manifestFile = file(manifestPath)
    }
}
```

PS: You will have to work your logic to determine when to set enabled false/true

Comment: I wanted it in java code main activity @raphaelbgr. Thanks for showing another way to add in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on degree of customizability you need the easiest option might be to use different versions of `AndroidManifest.xml` and put something like following in your `build.gradle` (using `custom` build flavor as example here)

```
        sourceSets {
            custom {
                if (myFlag == "true") {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/custom/AndroidManifest.xml"
                } else {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/custom_disabled/AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            }
        }
```